# Calculate modulo expression

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How does one evaluate the expression;

$$5\times52^{366} \mod367^1$$

I can infer from the exercise solutions that $52^{366} ≡ 1 \mod 367$, but why?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: Ah, that rings a bell. Thanks!